# mysql select * from table where is not null

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do a select * from *table* where is not null?

Essentially i want all results from a table but if a column has a null value for a row i dont want to see null in my output file which is a csv file?

Comment: Try WHERE WHAT IS NOT NULL

Comment: There are hundreds of rows so i dont want to have to do where row1 is not null and row2 is not null etc. i want to know if you can do any row in table is not null

Comment: the "WHAT" is supposed to be the column that is not allowed to be null. So, for example if you don't want column 2 to be null in your export, you say "WHERE column_2 IS NOT NULL"

Comment: Sorry i meant there are hundreds of columns not rows. I want to avoid specifying the columns as there are so many. Is it possible to exclude any null value regardless of the column?

Answer (score 2):

If you group_concat a bunch of columns and any of those columns contains a null then the result is null. So you could build a prepared statement using this characteristic to together with the column names harvested from information_schema columns.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (tID int, Name varchar(20),   Type varchar(20),   Start_Date date,  End_Date date);
insert into t values
(1,   null , 'Retail' , '2010-01-01', '2010-07-21'),
(1,   'Cust_1' , null   , '2010-07-22', '2012-05-17'),
(1,   'Cust_1' , 'Corp'   , '2012-05-18', '2012-12-31');



select group_concat(column_name) into @gc from information_schema.columns where table_name = 't' and table_schema = 'sandbox';
set @sqlstmt = concat('select * from t where concat(', @gc, ') is not null;');

#select @sqlstmt;

prepare sqlstmt from @sqlstmt;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```

Result

```
+------+--------+------+------------+------------+
| tID  | Name   | Type | Start_Date | End_Date   |
+------+--------+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | Cust_1 | Corp | 2012-05-18 | 2012-12-31 |
+------+--------+------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```